# how do i get my coroutine to update every frame in my BepInEx plugin?

Tags: c#, coroutines, il2cpp

in the code linked below, i am using bepinex and harmony to make a plugin for the game Sons of The Forest
the goal of the code attached is to log the value of an in-game variable every second, but the value of the variables in the class (labeled __instance) passed through the parameter for my coroutine (named Gores) does not change.
this results in my coroutine printing out the same result in the console forever.
How can i make my coroutine print out the value of _bleedingFactor while it updates through the game?

[image]

Comment: Do not post code as an image, use the code mark up and only include the code that is relevant to the question

Comment: "Code relevant to the question" will include the VailActor code. If this code is too large or you don't have access to this part of the source, you should create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example in a new project — writing new code that reproduces the same problem, while being concise enough to fit comfortably in the question in its entirety.